# Arrange LibSVM data in Column and Row struct pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, libsvm

I'm pretty new to C++ and I have some questions. 
I have similar at the following structure:

```
struct Data { 
  size_t num_rows, num_cols, num_feat;
  float *labels;
  Entry *data;
  inline Row GetRow(size_t i)
    return Row(label[i], ?pointer to the row data...
  inline Column GetColumn(size_t i)
    return Row(?pointer to the col data...
  inline Entry GetEntry(size_t row, size_t col)
    return data[?pointer to Entry
};

struct Row {
  float label;
  Entry *data;
  inline Entry GetEntry(size_t i)  // do I need pointer here?
    return data[i];
};

struct Column {
  Entry *data;
  inline Entry GetEntry(size_t i)  // do I need pointer here?
    return data[i];
};

struct Entry {
  size_t feat;
  float value;
  Entry(size_t i_feat, bst_float fvalue) : feat(feat), value(value) {}
};
```

Can you check the in-code questions?
How do I fill it?

Thank you.

Comment: The questions are too vague. Why not try and see if you need the pointers yourself?

Comment: You don't need pointers. This way, you return copies. However the class interface design looks like a horrible design. If you must have this awkward layout for some kind of interop with a legacy API, wokay. If not, use higher level abstractions in C++

Comment: The datasets are usually very big, so I can't get copies of anything. 
My objective is to have easy navigation and Row, Column and Entry permutations.